# How to use the same Wi-Fi adapter to connect to a wireless network, and broadcast an AP at the same time?

Tags: networking, wifi, router

I have a Wi-Fi router that runs OpenWRT. It connects to my home Wi-Fi and uses it for Internet access. At the same time, it broadcasts an access point itself and it is bridged with its LAN so other machines can connect to this router and get Internet access (through NAT). This is already implemented.

My question is, how do I do the same thing on my Linux machine? How is this implemented in OpenWRT?

Some clues... I noticed that the Wi-Fi router appears with the same MAC address on both networks (the one created by the home Wi-Fi, which this router is connected to, and the one created by itself). However, the router has two different host names on the two networks.

Comment: As far as I understand this, it requires special *hardware*, it isn't something you can do in software.

Answer (score 1):

Isnt your OpenWRT modem connected to your internet router with a cable? As far as I know is when you bring your interface in AP mode you cant use it to access the internet on the same time.

Comment: No. It is not connected to any Ethernet cable. Have you tried OpenWRT on your router?

Comment: I do but I dont know how to have it connected to the internet and as an AP at the same time. If I use this on other systems itś always with 2 wireless cards. I hope I can learn something from this question:-)

Comment: I am running OpenWrt Attitude Adjustment 12.09-beta2. In Network/Wifi I just used that "Add" button on the right of "radio0" to create a WWAN interface and connected it to my home Wi-Fi.